# Infopath 2013, search in repeating table with minimum and maximum value

Tags: sharepoint-2013, infopath

I have an infopath form with secondary datasources from sharePoint 2013 lists. I want to search in repeating tables in forms with a range of values. Eg: i have two input fields, the minimum and the maximum value, both have integer format. I want to query a secondary datasource (i don't retrieve the data on form load) with integer format also. I want to display in the repeating table only the rows with values in the range from input fields.

How can i do this in infopath 2013 with datasource from sharepoint server 2013?

Also i want to do the same with date values, how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Set two formatting rules on the table, one to hide rows where value is greater than maximum value and one to hide rows where value is less than minimum